# Calling view on linked server from a stored procedure in another database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, webforms, linked-server

I'm calling a stored procedure from asp.net using a connection string that grants me permissions to the database containing the stored procedure. This stored procedure though tries to call a view that is located on a linked server, resulting in a permission issue. What is the right way to allow my stored procedure to call the view on the linked server? I am not a sql server pro in the slightest.

Comment: The account that the asp.net request is running as needs SELECT permissions granted on the table(s) used in the remote view, which can get dicey.  Are you using pass-through authentication or is your app connecting to the database under a single service account?

Comment: Setting up permissions for linked servers isn't an introductory "thing". If you're new to SQL Server, I don't recommend messing around with the linked server permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The Sql account the app is using needs to be granted SELECT permission on the remote view it's trying to call.